# Pass a Number Value into a Shell Script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I regularly run a .sh script that has a list of menu options and expects a value from 1-7 that corresponds to a list of menu options. 99% of the time I use the same option (#6) so I'm trying to figure out a way pass the value of '6' into the script so that every time the script runs it sends the keystroke '6' once then just runs the script normally.

this is the command I've come up with so far:

```
echo '6' | /example/folder/script.sh
```

that sort of works except it repeatedly sends '6' every few seconds and never stops until I kill the script. I just want it to send 6 once then just run the script normally. what am I missing here?

the system I'm on is actually AIX using the ksh shell if that makes any difference

Comment: `echo '6'` sends `6` just _once_.  Is there some loop that you haven't shown us?

Comment: @John1024 The script is ridiculously complex 5000+ lines. from the end user perspective it's just a list of menus that and you enter a number to select the menu you want. But I guess from what you and wk are telling me what I'm doing should work so it must be something weird going on with this script then.. oh well...

Comment: If you want to send simulated input to a complex script, the right tool is [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) or pexpect.  It allows you to send the right inputs and the right times.  You can use `expect` _without_ changing your complex script in any way.

Comment: Without knowing what the script is doing, we’re all just guessing but it could be the trailing newline from you echo command that’s messing you up. It would be worth trying: echo –n  ‘6’ or printf ‘6’ just to see if that’s the case.

Comment: If it's an AIX system, why are you asking this question on AskUbuntu and not [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I would use commandline arguments, so you could run it like that

```
/example/folder/script.sh 6
```

Then, inside your script you could refer to it as `$1`

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that but, but either way I didn't create the script so I would rather not make change to it if possible.

Comment: @ryan, your solution should still work fine. It seems there is something wrong with how you run the command.